# How do I disable tree construction in Antlr?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

I have a grammar where I construct the tree myself. The rules look like this:

```
literal returns [ExpressionSyntax value]
    : exp1=NULL { $value = new IdentifierSyntax(exp1.Text); }
    | exp2=booleanLiteral { $value = new ValueSyntax(exp2.value, TypeCode.Boolean); }
```

This builds a complete tree and the last expression returns what I need.

**The problem is that Antlr itself is also building a tree into `TreeAdaptor`. How do I disable this?** I have already tried replacing the tree adapter with one that does nothing (i.e. returns `null`, even on the `Create` method) and I do still get a valid result (and it's a lot faster), so I know Antlr is not depending on this. However, I would like to just completely remove the `adaptor` code from the generated code. My grammar is C#, but from what I understand this should not make a difference.

Comment: does your grammar file have option { ouput=AST; }?

Comment: Yes, and I understood that that turns it on, but I can't change it. The only other option seems to be template which does something completely else...

Comment: The ANTLR reference states: Generate output templates (template) or trees (AST). The default  is to generate *nothing*. Have you tried to remove output= attribute altogether?

Comment: Tried that too. If I leave out the `output` option completely, I get `warning(149): ..\ES3.g:0:1: rewrite syntax or operator with no output option; setting output=AST`.

Comment: The rewrite rules probably rely on the underlying AST of particular type. And you want to replace AST with custom implementation. I see the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANTLR 3, there is no way to enable or disable tree construction at runtime. Trees will be created if and only if the grammar includes the `output=AST` option.

If you are constructing trees manually, then your grammar should omit the `output=AST` option.

**Note:** the `output=AST` option is automatically applied to your grammar if you use the AST operators `^` or `!` anywhere in your grammar, or if one or more of your parser rules includes a rewrite rule with the `->` operator. If you do not want to use the `output=AST` option and are seeing warning 149, then you need to go through your grammar and remove any instances of these operators as they are meaningless anyway without the `output=AST` option.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I've removed all the `^`, `!` and `->`'s from the grammar and now it changes the output. Now to get it to work again.